# Crashlytics reporting filename as hex and linenumber as zero for Android with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

For a Xamarin Forms project, Crashlytics reports for Android are always being shown with a hex string instead of filename and linenumber as zero `<20d52ef6870d4d40b207c467a668ad06>:0`, as in following example:

`Fatal Exception: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

`at MyNamespace.MyClass.MyFunction (ClassA myparameter) [0x0011a] in <20d52ef6870d4d40b207c467a668ad06>:0`

This is my configuration related to compiler and shrinker disabled:
[image: Compiler and shrinker configuration]

What could be my issue?